# LastModifiedDate is not updating

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that is moving nine (9) files from a source folder to a destination folder.

After the files have been moved, I am updating the LastWriteTime of each file to be

```
$currentTime = Get-Date
(Get-Item "somefilename").LastWriteTime  = $currentTime.AddMinutes(1)
(Get-Item "someotherfilename").LastWriteTime  = $currentTime.AddMinutes(2)
```

After the script runs all the modified times are the same! Also, they are the current time. None of them get updated to the future time. What could be the problem.

I ran the script as admin, same problem. When I print the LastWriteTim to the console, it has the correct value, but when I look on the file properties, it is the wrong value.

Comment: I can't reproduce, getting expected results with `gci;gci|%{$_.LastWriteTime=[datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(3)};gci`

Comment: @LotPings I know I have seen that work as well in the past, but I always had fullcontrol or admin-rights on any of the systems where I ran a script like that. But if the rights are just Modify in stead of Full Control things might be different (see my answer as well). I'm not near any PC on which I can verify this currently. Will check tomorrow when I'm in the office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about this, but I've seen similar problems in the past when you have not enough access-rights on the target folder.

There is a difference between Modify (aka ReadWrite) and Full-Control rights.
On many filesystems Full-Control is needed to be allowed to change the time-attributes (and access-rights attributes) of a file.
If you only have "modify" you can create/delete files, but you can't change attributes like the LastWrite timestamp. This will get set automatically when the file is copied and will probably be identical to '$currenttime' with maybe a few seconds difference, depending on what exactly is happening in your script and how much time that takes.

Comment: Nope, this is not the problem. I tried running as admin and all.

Comment: @user77232 Is that target folder on a local drive or an a network-drive ? If it is local, which filesystem is used and is it on a removable device or not? This all makes for subtle differences in the way Windows handles permissions.

Comment: The target is the boot disk C:\ my downloads folder of my user profile.

Comment: @user77232 Downloads folder ? In that case the virusscanner (or AppLocker if enabled) may keep the file briefly locked which prevents the update of the timestamp.

Comment: how do you detect that?

Comment: great I'm an idiot. Been changing the wrong property. It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

i know this is an old post, but maybe this helps someone in future:

The setter for the lastwritetime and lastaccesstime directly from the folder object seems to bebugged. Use System.IO.Directory's SetLastAccessTime and/or SetLastWriteTime methods instead:

[System.IO.Directory]::SetLastAccessTime($DestinationFolderPath, $NewDate)
[System.IO.Directory]::SetLastWriteTime($DestinationFolderPath, $NewDate)